# Streaming Library VLC Android

Tags: android, stream, streaming, libvlc

Currently we are developing an Android application for streaming. We are looking for an alternative library, because the VLC library isn't finished yet. We currently used the Vitamio library, but it works a little buggy.

- Doesn't play MMS immediately
- Some HTTP Stream will not start
- Can't edit the controls

Are there any other third party libraries who cover the following streams: HTTP Live streaming (apple), RTSP and MMS. And also are better documented? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Also GStreamer provides a version for android (arm processor).

Here you can find the libraries http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/android/1.0.7/

Answer (score 0):

You can look at wrapping the FFMPEG library and using it.